# Is it possible to create a Shortcut that links a foto to a marker on a map?

Tags: ios, camera, geolocation, ipados, shortcuts-app

I'd like to create an iOS / ipadOS Shortcut that, when called, lets me take a photograph, add a caption and store the device's current position as a map marker. The idea is to mark interesting locations for a "proper" photography session, so I can return there with better gear when the light is right.

I'm completely open with regard to the apps involved -- as long as it outputs some sort of GPX or KML.

It does not seem trivially possible with iOS's bundled actions and apps -- so how can I create such a Shortcut?

Comment: iPhone photos contain a location based on the phone's position. You can view them in Maps. Maps, however, uses postcodes for navigation, so if you decide to go back to an out of the way location, you might have to visually follow the pin cross-country rather than use the satnav. The standard photo editor also allows you to add a description [which I haven't tested, but presumably goes in the exif data]

Comment: @Tetsujin -- thanks, I'm aware of that possibility. I found it too clunky in everyday use, especially since you can't add notes to such an image. My target is to create several GPX files containing interesting locations grouped by some sort of metadata, so I want to start out using a Shortcut since it'll grow into a workflow over time.

Answer (score 0):

The easy part of this is to have a shortcut add photos to a scouting album. You can then consume that album later to get geotagged items or export and copy / paste the exif data using a third party app.

As described, you might need to create a proper app to bulk export GPX or KML on iOS since I can’t see how to do that except using macOS and some heavier weight automation than iOS shortcuts.